# How to get an output of 100V from a 3.3 V pulse waveform?

Tags: high-voltage, protection

We have a problem when trying to drive a piezo transducer(the output of microcontroller is a 3.3V pulse, but the piezo works around 100V-300V, so we have to convert the 3.3V pulse to 100V pulse).

Does anyone has any idea about how to design the circuit? And how to design the protection circuit between the 100V drive voltage and the small voltage received by the transducer?

Comment: Buy a pulser IC. There are a great many out there. (e.g. [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/tc6320.pdf))

Answer (score 2):

The TI DRV2700 is a a part that is specifically designed to generate high voltage pulses for driving piezos. It has a built in boost converter for generating the 105V high voltage output from a 3-5v input.

You can read more about it here...

http://www.ti.com/product/DRV2700

Comment: Thanks for your reply. actually, I have 2 optional plans.

Answer (score -3):

There is no way you can magically create 100-300 VDC from 3.3 VDC. Best you can try to do is use a 110/115 VAC power supply and rectify it to dc.

Comment: I'll speak for the others who apparently haven't : that is wrong. Transistors can do just that, see Tom Carpenter's comment for example (a piezo usually doesn't draw much current).