# Earth resistivity meter design

Tags: boost, high-voltage

I would like to design an [earth resistivity meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_survey) for use in archaeological surveying. This is essentially a current source placed in the ground and a ohmmeter to measure the resistance between the probes. This tells us something of the composition and moisture content of the soil, and whether there might be archaeological features beneath the topsoil.

An example of a commercial "res meter" is the [Geoscan RM15-D](http://www.geoscan-research.co.uk/RM15_v9_Data_Sheet.pdf), and John Becker wrote an [article](http://www.slideshare.net/jplateado/earth-resistivity-logger-john-becker) in *Everyday Practical Electronics* about 20 years ago with a design for one. The drawback with that one is it uses +/-5v on the probes which limits its usefulness in dry or very rocky soils. The Geoscan machine can output at either 40v or 100v (peak-to-peak I *think*) which makes it 
a more versatile device. An AC-coupled waveform is needed to reduce the capacitive effects of the soil.

So what I would like to design is a circuit that gets me somewhere near the specification of the RM15-D:

- up to 100v p-p AC at <150Hz at a user-selectable constant current of 0.1mA to 10mA
- powered by a rechargeable LiPo/Li-ion battery
- be as lightweight as possible because frail archaeologists need to lug this thing around bramble patches all day

The circuit in the article uses a simple pulse train as its output waveform, and while the actual waveform shape doesn't appear to matter a great deal (as long as it is AC coupled), the potential for very high transient voltages seems to me undesirable. Assume for the purposes of this that I can generate a low voltage sine wave to be fed into the circuit. Presumably some amount of isolation will be needed as well.

What would be the recommended way of achieving this? Would using something as simple as a transformer be sufficient, or perhaps something like a DRV2700 as has been mentioned in [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/189556/how-to-get-an-output-of-100v-from-a-3-3-v-pulse-waveform) SE question?

Comment: One would assume that the highest contributor to soil resistivity is the soil moisture content?

Comment: What is the range of the values expected?

Comment: The RM15-D spec sheet gives a maximum contact resistance range of 10kΩ to 1MΩ at 100v

Comment: A stupid question: Why a regular ohmmeter can't be used for this purpose?

Comment: If you are an archeologist, then probably you aren't a EE freak. IMO building such instrument requires a good knowledge that only few members on this forum have. I suggest you to buy a made meter, plenty of them exist since they are used for earthing inspection.

Comment: Surely Marko, if I were an EE freak (I consider myself a hobbyist), I wouldn't be asking questions - or has SE become so exclusive that I need to be an experienced professional before asking a question? It's a good job I am thick-skinned otherwise I might be scared off by your elitism. My assumption is if a working device can be published in a hobbyist magazine, it's not beyond a hobbyist's ken to improve upon it. I understand I may not be asking the right question - in which case some gentle guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: @MerseyViking Perhaps I expressed my opinion in a not appropiate way, it has nothing to to about elitism. I just think in the way, what I would do in similar situation. Even if I am an EE enthusiast, I would buy such instrument, I have various instrument: scope, insulation tester, DMM,...I bougth them all, because I want to have a valuable result, that's all. You can also buy a used one, since the professionals have to have the calibration and approval every 2 years, or so. Therefore they sell them and buy new.

Comment: Don't think of a archaeological res meter as a piece of lab equipment, but as something people throw in the back of a 4 wheel drive and generally abuse. Indeed, absolute measurements aren't important (as long as they are consistent), we are looking for variations in soil moisture at typically a 1m grid spacing over a usually large area in as short a time as possible. Also, archaeologists have no money - local archaeology societies are mostly volunteer-based, and finding $5000+ for a machine is very hard, and they don't tend to get resold because of it.

Comment: Please check the ebay: http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=earth+ground+resistance+tester&_pgn=2&_skc=50&rt=nc  , the Fluke is for sure the best you can get, but also some chinese instumnts like Mastech perhaps are enough good for your use, The article describes those earth resitance meters, they are widely used in grounding, it's not an archealogy invention.

Comment: I'm no expert on those sorts of devices, but I suspect they would be inappropriate otherwise archaeologists would be using those! Check the Wikipedia article I linked to for a general description of operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a big project and cannot be answered in detail in a simple way. The crux of your question/problem seems to be the generation of the 40 - 100V 'AC' with a variable/preset 'constant current' so that's what I've concentrated on. There are other solutions but this is how I would approach it.

Taking an overview of the project gave me a block diagram like this.

[image]

I've expanded the blocks for the 'AC' generation. By generating a DC high voltage first and then converting it to AC using an H bridge it allows the output frequency to the probes be easily changed. The output is a squarewave. The probes need an AC signal to prevent polarisation but the waveform is not important.

Rather than trying to produce a constant current I went for the same approach as described in the EPE project - using switched **current limiting resistors**. This produces a very simple and easily constructed (bi-directional) circuit.

The high voltage (shown as 100V but could be 40V if needed) is generated using any suitable dc-dc converter (such as an LT8331). By adding an H bridge circuit, supplied by the high voltage, the bridge outputs can be continuously reversed by a bi-phase clock/driver circuit supplying current to the probes. (*a more common use is to reverse current through a motor)* There are lots of examples of this type of circuit on the net.

This H bridge could be driven by a simple 'clock' type oscillator (such as a 555 astable) or from a microcontroller output (with suitable interfaces to protect against the high voltage).

Looking at the rest of the circuit I think you'll also need to include a GPS module (so you know where the reading was taken), some form of data logging system (to record the data), an interface to an external computer if the data isn't portable (i.e. on a memory stick or card), a microcontroller to handle the data flow,timing readings, key input, display etc., some form of  voltage measurement system that can be converted to digital data for the data logger, a keyboard or set of keys to operate different functions and some form of display to let you know what's happening. As I said - this is a big project - good luck!

Comment: That's fantastic, thanks JIm. Just the sort of thing I was after. The rest of the device - microcontroller, displays, input, logging and all that are fairly straightforward for me as a programmer (my main job) and tinkerer (I made an internet-controlled kettle for a client once - don't ask, but I got paid). It was really just the high voltage stuff that I didn't want to mess around with until I had something to work from. The GPS part generally isn't used - we divide the site into 30m squares that we survey in with theodolites and paper maps (archaeologists are slow movers with technology).

Answer (score 1):

I will avoid long comments, so I will try to give you some my point of view. I have read the articles and came to the conclusion that archealogy instruments use the same principle as ground test meters. The difference is data logging, where for archealogy you would need also a GPS location of taken measuring and a visualization software. Cheap soil resistance meters use high frequency, while good ones use low frequency.
Now top of the tops instrument like Fluke 1625-2 GEO Earth Ground Tester, it can measure soil with 55, 94, 105, 111, 128 Hz. http://en-us.fluke.com/products/earth-ground/fluke-1625-2-geo-earth-ground-tester-kit.html#techspecs, the Fluke 1623-2 has 128Hz signal, then you have a chinese MASTECH MS2306 with 94, 128 Hz, Mastech MS2307, 
All these instruments have no GPS possibility, but they store the measuremnts and you can download trough USB. I have found also http://www.sonel.pl/en/katalog-produktow/electrical-safety-measurements/mru-200.html this device has built in GPS and stores the measurements with position.
IMO the ideal meter for you is kind of low frequency and possibility to output measures on RS232 port, where you connect with kind of Arduino or other board to have a DGPS device and a SD card storage. I doubt, that the instruments described on the articles have such precision as professional earth meters, they just make some basic meter and they are selling PC software.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for that Marko - my budget could stretch to a fairly cheap one to play around with and compare results with one designed for archaeology.

Comment: Sure, go ahead. I'm glad to see you have found a solution. Altrough I'm not such expert to build these instruments myself.